# Is there a way to detect cold start in Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

When my GCF function is in a cold start state, I need to send a "wait" signal to the invoking endpoint to let it know that response time may be a bit slower. (For context, this is the back-end of a Slack slash function, which requires an initial response within three seconds. We're seeing > 3s gcf spin-up time at cold start though).

If relevant, the relevant cloud function is also performing calls to firestore.

Is there a way to detect when a cloud function is spinning up from cold start? Can't find any mention of this anywhere... Thank you.

Comment: There is no API that you can call. You must design into your software that a function might have a cold start delay. If you required fast startup (no cold start) then you will need to implement your own compute services.

Comment: What is you language? What is the memory of your function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can migrate Cloud Functions to App Engine in order to have warm up [requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/configuring-warmup-requests) and avoid the cold start.

As @John Hanley mention the only way to reduce the cold boot time is optimizing your deployed function.

Google recommends:

- Always delete temporary files
- Use dependencies wisely
- Use global variables to reuse objects in future invocations
- Do lazy initialization of global variables

Check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOXrwFqR6kY) to know the best practices for Could Functions

Comment: Ok, thank you. I know we can hack our way to semi-warm cloud functions w/ a cron job but that's clearly sub-optimal, so I'll have a look at the above. Thanks.